# Load Subset of CSVs Within AWS Glue From S3 Using PySpark

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have a collection of directories within S3 that I"m attempting to read from.  The CSVs are organized by date folders.  I have a large collection of folders and I'd only like to pull recent dates:

The following code pulls data from all folders:

```
data = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://bucket/shopify/orders/"],"recurse":True}, format = "csv",format_options={
        "separator": ",",
        "withHeader":True
        }).toDF()
```

However to pull 2022 data, I've been trying the below, but it doesn't seem to work

```
data = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://bucket/shopify/orders/2022_*/"],"recurse":True}, format = "csv",format_options={
        "separator": ",",
        "withHeader":True
        }).toDF()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The path is the problem.  This isn't a valid path: `s3://bucket/shopify/orders/2022_*/`

Comment: figured it out, wrote the path using spark.read.format

Comment: That's great.  Can you post an answer to your question, which shows how you solved this?